# Mysql Not In (null) doesn't show records

Tags: mysql

```
select * from items where id is not null;
```

This query returns all correct records, but this one :

```
select * from items where id not in (null);
```

shows nothing. Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: `null` is not a value. For the same reason you can't do `id = null`, you cannot do `not in (null)`

Comment: ...and this is the reason why the operator `IS` exists.

Comment: Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null is not value, that is why we use `is not null` or `is null` expression.

in your second case

```
select * from items where id not in (null);
```

is equal to

```
select * from items where id != null;
```

which evaluates nothing because id is neither satisfies `= null` nor satisfies `!= null`

Answer (score 1):

Your second query will not work because `null` is not a value, it is `undefined`, that's why you can't use it with any sql operator. Instead you can re-write your second query like this :

```
select * from items where coalesce(id, '') not in ('');
```

But this will also exclude the result for `id = ''` So use of the first query is the best solution in this case which is :

```
select * from items where id is not null;
```

Get more information about `NULL` in mysql from [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)